# Assign some empty value to Generic class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I am parsing API's using Generic Default model. Following is my BaseModel Class

```
class BaseModel<T : Codable>: Codable {
    var StatusCode : Int
    var StatusMessage : String
    var Data : T
    var ErrorMessage : String
    }
```

I am not using optional's to avoid un wrap instead i provide it some default value with fallowing initialiser.

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.StatusCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .StatusCode) ?? -1
            self.StatusMessage = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .StatusMessage) ?? "no message"
            self.Data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .Data) ?? 
            self.ErrorMessage = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .ErrorMessage) ?? "default error"
        }
    }
```

i assign empty string to String value's and -1 to Int value's. I got stuck assigning some value to Generic ? What a Generic Data type accept like i assign `""` empty string to String's not a nit ?

Comment: "i assign empty string to String value's and -1 to Int value" you should really not do that. This is what optionals are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since T conforms to `Codable` you can use the same `init(from:)` from the `Decodable` protocol

```
self.Data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .Data) ?? T(from: decoder)
```

This of course requires that T can create an "empty" object, if it can't I believe you need to go with optional

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is constrain `T` to an additional protocol `HasDefaultValue`:

```
protocol HasDefaultValue {
    static var defaultValue: Self { get }
}

class BaseModel<T : Codable & HasDefaultValue>: Codable {
    var StatusCode : Int
    var StatusMessage : String
    var Data : T
    var ErrorMessage : String
}
```

And you can conform `String`, `Int` and whatever type you want to `HasDefaultValue`:

```
extension String : HasDefaultValue {
    static let defaultValue = ""
}

extension Int : HasDefaultValue {
    static let defaultValue = -1
}

extension Optional : HasDefaultValue {
    static var defaultValue: Optional<Wrapped> { return Optional.none }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
self.Data = try container.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey: .Data) ?? T.defaultValue
```

Comment: it show error "Protocol 'HasDefaultValue' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" on line `class BaseModel<T : Codable & HasDefaultValue>: Codable {`

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon really? It *is* used as a generic constraint though.

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon [I can't reproduce your error](https://repl.it/repls/NocturnalOrangeredOutcomes)